# magmi configurable product import fine, m2epro lists only "simple" products on ebay

Tags: magento, magmi, m2e-pro

So I list a configurable product through magmi to Magent just fine. Looks gook.

Then I push the item to eBay via m2epro and only the simple products list (as individual products). What am I missing? Anyone have any luck with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have the "Ignore Variations" set to "Yes" in your Price, Quantity and Format Policy.

Go to Sell on eBay > Configuration > Policies and amend as appropriate.

Also a tip is to list the main configurable product rather than the simple products, as they'll always list individually.

And also another tip is to note that by default M2E Pro doesn't allow you to list duplicates by default

If you're using the simple mode in M2EPro, you'll have to change to the advanced mode (see this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5DU4aTVuck on how to do this) and the settings are then in Sell on eBay > Configuration > General and the setting you need is on the bottom called "prevent duplicates".